# geoinfo with python

Tags: python, geo

I want to figure out where a host is located, in which country. There are sites that look up this information (e.g. http://geoip.flagfox.net/). Before writing a scraper, I would like to
ask if you know a python API for this task.

**Update:** following the link of Ashwini Chaudhary, I made my own ip2country converter. Available [here](https://github.com/jabbalaci/jabbapylib/blob/master/jabbapylib/network/geoinfo.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://netsekure.org/wp-content/uploads/ip2loc.py

run this script from command prompt : `python ip2loc.py all`

Comment: Thanks, the "geoplugin" part works fine. geoplugin has some nice [web services](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices) too, including JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If high accuracy is not a concern, MaxMind's free databases ([Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) / [City](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity)) could offer an off-line solution. It has a [Python API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/python).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

http://www.hostip.info/

Its very easy with this like below

```
import urllib
response = urllib.urlopen('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19&position=true').read()
print(response)
```